# How to set default reply-to address in webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I am using [Webform Reply to](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_reply_to) module to set `Reply to address` for mails sent from webforms. This feature works fine but for each webform creation I have to set `Reply to address` because by default it will select  `Default: No Reply-To address` option. But I want to select a default address as `xyz@mail.com` . So how can i achieve that?? For reference see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your form, create an email field  that contains the email you want to have for your reply-to.  now hide it(don't display..making it private might suit, or use css).  This hidden email field value will be accessible in the component pulldown